# Kernel#open with a passed in File object

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to debug/diagnose some strange behaviour, and hoping someone can have some insight for me. This is in Ruby 1.9.3.

We've got some code that opens an uploaded file to determine its MIME type, which boils down to:

```rb
open(file) { |f| get_mime_type(f) }
```

Pretty straightforward. In this case, file is actually a File object (or a Rack::Test::UploadedFile in our test suite), not a path, but `open` seems to work fine with a file object.

... Except that we now have a new member of the team and it's not working for him. His environment is set up for the most part the same way (anything relevant I could think of is identical - ruby version and patchlevel, rails version, installed gems), but on his machine, when a file object is passed to `open`, it returns a file object and ignores the block altogether. Passing in a path instead of a file object, however, works:

```rb
open(file.path) { |f| get_mime_type(f) }
```

So that's our temporary fix, but what I'm trying to figure out is *why* this is happening? I'd appreciate any insight!

Comment: If you're certain he's on 1.9.3, then this is really weird -- are you certain you're calling `Kernel#open` and not some local method?  Perhaps try ensuring this by tacking a `Kernel.` to the beginning of `open()`.

Comment: Yeah, he's definitely on 1.9.3, and adding on `Kernel` makes no difference!

Comment: Well, it sounds like either 1) someone monkey-patched `Kernel`, or 2) the actual code doesn't quite "boil down" to what you're showing.  I certainly can't think of any other possibilities right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither is true. The codebase is exactly the same on the new dev's local machine as each of the other devs, and here's the actual code: https://github.com/hanklords/shared-mime-info/blob/master/lib/shared-mime-info.rb#L234-L242 (for this specific case, `check_special` is nil)

Comment: Is `open` working for him in other cases, like https://github.com/hanklords/shared-mime-info/blob/master/lib/shared-mime-info.rb#L220-L226 ?

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm trying to figure out is why this is happening?

The first argument of `Kernel#open` is [**not supposed**](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel#open-instance_method) to work with a `File` object but rather with a `String` object representing a *path*. The fact that it is working for some machines is not the proof of it being valid or a suggested way of using `open`.

You should definitely keep using:

```
open(file.path) { |f| get_mime_type(f) }
```